# How to cancel many Async Tasks immediately when I use HttpClient？

Tags: c#, task, dotnet-httpclient

I have a class like below.

```
class Service
{
    private HttpClient client;
    public Service()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("a uriString");  //"a uriString" refers to a real uri string.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
    public async Task<Result> DoSomeWork()
    {
        var post = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        post.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value")); //"key" "value" refers to real 
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(post);
        try
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync("requestUri", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In another UI class,

```
Service service = new Service();
```

it also contains a timer which interval is 1 second. In its Tick Handler method, some code like this:

```
async void testTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await service.DoSomeWork();
}
```

In this program, I want to post data to a website every second. I find that many requests are pending. If 10 minutes passed, I want to start another Task immediately. How can I cancel some Tasks before?
If I use `CancellationTokenSource` class，I find it also can't cancel so many tasks immediately. Is there a method like `Thread.Abort()` to abort a thread? Or how can I complete this program in another way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use `CancellationTokenSource` class，I find it also can't cancel so many tasks immediately.

Sure it can. [A single `CancellationTokenSource` cancels its own `CancellationToken`, and that same `CancellationToken` can be copied between multiple operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `CancellationTokenSource` is exactly what you should use.

Some of the higher-level `HttpClient` methods (such as `GetStringAsync`) do not support `CancellationToken` out of the box, but Lucian Wischik has a [good blog post on adding that support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/12/08/await-httpclient-getstringasync-and-cancellation.aspx).

Comment: I tried again. I create and start a new Task with a token in my `testTimer_Tick` function. In another click event handler I call the Cancel() method. Only If I test the task state in a while loop can I capture it. Then I can throw the exception, but I find I its sub tasks not be canceled. Are the http requests buffered? Or how can I cancel the http request tasks.

Comment: @Jackliu91: You need to pass the `CancellationToken` through to all async operations your method calls.